# How do I use JpaRepository in a backend thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface PackageRepository extends JpaRepository<DocPackage, String> {
}
```

Now I'm able to use this without any problem from my REST services by using:

```
@Resource
PackageRepository repo;
```

I can make transactional calls on it with no problem.

However when I try to load this from a worker thread:

```
public class MyWorker implements Runnable {
    @Resource
    PackageRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    private void doSomething() {
        DocPackage pck = repo.findOne("key");
        pck.setStatus(2);
        repo.saveAndFlush(pck);
    }

    public void run() {
        //stuff
        doSomething();
        //other stuff
    }
}

new Thread(new MyWorker()).start();
```

I'm able to do reads on this repo just fine, but whenever I save and flush I get the exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Is there any way to get this done correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring, by default, use proxies. This mean `@Transaction` works only when method called from outside of class.

To fix it extract you method to service. Inject your service in `MyWorker` and call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `@Transactional` annotation to your method